# How to paginate Files from a Folder using cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

Basically I want to paginate the contents of a folder using the Folder/File classes from CakePHP.

I have this in my controller:

```
$dir = new Folder('img/gallery/'.$gallery[0]['Gallery']['path']);
$file = $dir->find('.*', true);
$this->set('files', $file);
```

Now I want to paginate the results. They look like this:

```
array (size=188)
0 => string '52652681-023c-4e51-99b5-16cccbdd56cb.jpeg' (length=41)
1 => string '526f4034-9b6c-47c8-94f9-10e0cbdd56cb.jpeg' (length=41)
2 => string 'DSCF0232.JPG' (length=12)
3 => string 'DSCF0233.JPG' (length=12)
4 => string 'DSCF0234.JPG' (length=12)
```

How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use simple php code to do that. calculate first the total of pages:

```
$pageSize = 10;    
$totalPages = (count($file) + $pageSize - 1) / $pageSize;

$this->set('totalPages ', $totalPages);
```

In your template already you can do this

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $totalPages; $i ++){
    echo '<a href="YOUR_URI?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
}
```

Now when a user click on the link sending the page he wants to see you will show only that part of the array and not all `$file` list.

```
$page = intval($_GET['page']);
$dir = new Folder('img/gallery/'.$gallery[0]['Gallery']['path']);
$file = $dir->find('.*', true);
$pageSize = 10;    
$totalPages = (count($file) + $pageSize - 1) / $pageSize;
$index = $page * $pageSize;
$file_list = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $pageSize; $i ++){
   if(isset($file[$index+$i]))
   $file_list[] = $file[$index+$i];
}
$this->set('totalPages ', $totalPages);
$this->set('files', $file_list);
```

This is the idea.